# SQL Server: use value from select case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if there is a way to use a value returned by case statement in the same select?

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    firstValue,
    secondValue,
    CASE 
       WHEN fistValue > secondValue 
          THEN firstValue 
       ELSE SecondValue 
    END as Value,
    CASE 
       WHEN value > 5 
          THEN 'something' 
    END
FROM 
    SomeTable
```

But this will result in invalid column name for value.

Comment: No, it is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;with cteSomeValues as
(
Select 
        id,
        name,
        firstValue,
        secondValue,
        CASE WHEN fistValue > secondValue THEN firstValue ELSE SecondValue END as Value
        FROM SomeTable
)
Select 
        id,
        name,
        firstValue,
        secondValue,
        Value,
        CASE WHEN value > 5 then 'something' END
FROM cteSomeValues
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
;WITH CTE AS(
Select 
id,name,firstValue,secondValue,
(CASE WHEN fistValue > secondValue THEN firstValue ELSE SecondValue END) as Value,
FROM SomeTable
) select  id, name, firstValue,secondValue,case when value > 5 then 'something'  END as VALUECOLUMN from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put , between two case.

```
Select 
        id,
        name,
        firstValue,
        secondValue,
        CASE WHEN fistValue > secondValue THEN firstValue ELSE SecondValue END as Value,
        CASE WHEN value > 5 then 'something' END
        FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to do it is this.

```
select t.id, 
       t.Name, 
       t.firstvalue, 
       t.secondvalue, 
       case
         when t.value = 5 then 'something' 
       end
from ( SELECT id,
              name,
              firstValue,
              secondValue,
              CASE 
                WHEN fistValue > secondValue THEN firstValue 
                ELSE SecondValue 
              END as Value
       FROM   SomeTable
     ) t
```